# Календарь: выбор даты посещения магазина

Tags: php, календарь

Добрый день! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно написать календарь,в котором пользователь может выбрать дату и время посещения магазина, но выбор даты должен ограничиваться десятью днями от текущей даты, и чтобы эта дата и время была записана в БД....Sad

**Обновление** 
Листинг

```
$startData1 = date("m",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")));
$startData2 = date("Y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")));
kalendar ($startData1,$startData2);
echo "</td><td width=20> </td><td valign='top'>";
$day =  date("d");
$minusday = 0;
if ($day > 20 ) $minusday = 3;
$startData1 = date("m",mktime(0,0,0,date("m")+1,date("d")-$minusday));
    $startData2 = date("Y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m")+1,date("d")-$minusday));
    kalendar ($startData1,$startData2);
```

Пока только это, но ничего не выводится. Пытался разобраться с готовыми календарями,сделать там ограничение в 10 дней, но ничего не получалось.

Мне просто хотелось бы узнать как сделать ограничение на кол-во дней, чтобы, допустим, 10 дней было доступно для выбора? И как можно реализовать запись этого выбора в БД?

Comment: Ну, и что написали?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы за вас все сделали и поднесли на мисочке ?

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: switch переключатель. 

Answer (score 1):

Создайте переменную count. И при каждом выборе дня добавить `+1`

```
count++;
```

Ничего сложного.

Comment: спасибо большое,попробую